# How can I diagnose async/await deadlocks?

Tags: c#, debugging, async

I am working with a new codebase that makes heavy use of async/await. Most of the people on my team are also fairly new to async/await. We generally tend to hold to [Best Practices as Specified by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), but generally need our context to flow through the async call and are working with libraries that don't `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Combine all of those things and we run into async deadlocks described in the article... weekly. They don't show up during unit testing, because our mocked data sources (usually via `Task.FromResult`) aren't enough to trigger the deadlock. So during runtime or integration tests, some service call just goes out to lunch and never returns. That kills the servers, and generally makes a mess of things.

The problem is that tracking down where the mistake was made (usually just not being async all the way up) generally involves manual code inspection, which is time consuming and not automate-able.

What's a better way of diagnosing what caused the deadlock?

Comment: Good question;  I've wondered this myself.  Have you read [this guy's collection of `async` articles](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - maybe not all, but I've read some. More "Make sure to do these two/three things everywhere or else your code will die a horrible death at runtime".

Comment: Are you open to dropping async or reducing its usage to the most beneficial points? Async IO is not all or nothing.

Comment: @usr - it largely _is_ all or nothing. You don't get benefits if the asynchrony is being done in a blocking context. But sure, I am open to adjusting the design, though that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If you can reproduce the deadlock, can't you just look at the stack trace to see the blocking call?

Comment: @svick - it's not a traditional deadlock in that sense. (As I understand it) The tasks are waiting  for an event to signal them to do their continuation. Since they're not actively blocked waiting for that event, none of the threads are associated with the await.

Comment: If the problem is "not async all the way", then that means that one half of the deadlock is a traditional deadlock and should be visible in the stack trace of the synchronization context thread.

Comment: Are the deadlocking threads/processes on the same hardware, so you can get simultaneous stack traces as @svick suggested? If A is waiting for something from B, and B is waiting for something from A, this should be clear from examining both of their stacks.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - it is not clear (as far as I can tell), since the threads are not actively waiting - at least not on anything related to the await. They've been returned to the thread pool for the TPL to grab.

Answer (score 4):

Ok - I am not sure whether the following will be of any help to you, because I made some assumptions in developing a solution which may or may not be true in your case. Maybe my "solution" is too theoretical and only works for artifical examples - I have not done any testing beyond the stuff below.
In addition, I would see the following more a workaround than a real solution but considering the lack of responses I think it might still be better than nothing (I kept watching your question waiting for a solution, but not seeing one getting posted I started playing around with the issue).

But enough said: Let's say we have a simple data service which can be used to retrieve an integer:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    Task<int> LoadMagicInteger();
}
```

A simple implementation uses asynchronous code:

```
public sealed class CustomDataService
    : IDataService
{
    public async Task<int> LoadMagicInteger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LoadMagicInteger - 1");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("LoadMagicInteger - 2");
        var result = 42;
        Console.WriteLine("LoadMagicInteger - 3");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("LoadMagicInteger - 4");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, a problem arises, if we are using the code "incorrectly" as illustrated by this class. `Foo` incorrectly accesses `Task.Result` instead of `await`ing the result like `Bar` does:

```
public sealed class ClassToTest
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;

    public ClassToTest(IDataService dataService)
    {
        this._dataService = dataService;
    }

    public async Task<int> Foo()
    {
        var result = this._dataService.LoadMagicInteger().Result;
        return result;
    }
    public async Task<int> Bar()
    {
        var result = await this._dataService.LoadMagicInteger();
        return result;
    }
}
```

What we (you) now need is a way to write a test which succeeds when calling `Bar` but fails when calling `Foo` (at least if I understood the question correctly ;-) ).

I'll let the code speak; here's what I came up with (using Visual Studio tests, but it should work using NUnit, too):

`DataServiceMock` utilizes `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. This allows us to set the result at a defined point in the test run which leads to the following test. Note that we are using a delegate to pass back the TaskCompletionSource back into the test. You might also put this into the Initialize method of the test and use properties.

```
TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = null;
this._dataService.LoadMagicIntegerMock = t => tcs = t;

Task<int> task = null;
TaskTestHelper.AssertDoesNotBlock(() => task = this._instance.Foo());

tcs.TrySetResult(42);

var result = task.Result;
Assert.AreEqual(42, result);

this._end = true;
```

What's happening here is that we first verify that we can leave the method without blocking (this would not work if someone accessed `Task.Result` - in this case we would run into a timeout as the result of the task is not made available until after the method has returned).
Then, we set the result (now the method can execute) and we verify the result (inside a unit test we can access Task.Result as we actually *want* the blocking to occur).

Complete test class - `BarTest` succeeds and `FooTest` fails as desired.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private DataServiceMock _dataService;
    private ClassToTest _instance;
    private bool _end;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        this._dataService = new DataServiceMock();
        this._instance = new ClassToTest(this._dataService);

        this._end = false;
    }
    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(this._end);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FooTest()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = null;
        this._dataService.LoadMagicIntegerMock = t => tcs = t;

        Task<int> task = null;
        TaskTestHelper.AssertDoesNotBlock(() => task = this._instance.Foo());

        tcs.TrySetResult(42);

        var result = task.Result;
        Assert.AreEqual(42, result);

        this._end = true;
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void BarTest()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = null;
        this._dataService.LoadMagicIntegerMock = t => tcs = t;

        Task<int> task = null;
        TaskTestHelper.AssertDoesNotBlock(() => task = this._instance.Bar());

        tcs.TrySetResult(42);

        var result = task.Result;
        Assert.AreEqual(42, result);

        this._end = true;
    }
}
```

And a little helper class to test for deadlocks / timeouts:

```
public static class TaskTestHelper
{
    public static void AssertDoesNotBlock(Action action, int timeout = 1000)
    {
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);

        Task.WaitAny(timeoutTask, task);

        Assert.IsTrue(task.IsCompleted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I'm planning to try your code myself when I have some time (I don't actually know for sure if it works or not), but kudos and an upvote for the effort.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a strategy that I used in a huge and very, very multithreaded application:

First, you need some data structure around a mutex (unfortunately) and make no synchronising calls directory. In that data structure, there's a link to any previously locked mutex. Every mutex has a "level" starting at 0, which you assign when the mutex is created and can never change.

And the rule is: If a mutex is locked, you must only ever lock other mutexes at a lower level. If you follow that rule, then you can't have deadlocks. When you find a violation, your application is still up and running just fine.

When you find a violation, there are two possibilities: You may have assigned the levels wrong. You locked A followed by locking B, so B should have had a lower level. So you fix the level and try again.

The other possibility: You can't fix it. Some code of yours locks A followed by locking B, while some other code locks B followed by locking A. There's no way to assign the levels to allow this. And of course this is a potential deadlock: If both codes run simultaneously on different threads, there's a chance of deadlock.

After introducing this, there was a rather short phase where levels had to be adjusted, followed by a longer phase where potential deadlocks were found.

Comment: I'm sorry, how does that apply to async/await behavior? I can't realistically inject a custom mutex management structure into the Task Parallel Library.

Answer (score -3):

Are you using Async/Await so you can parallelize expensive calls like to a database?  Depending on the execution path in the DB this might not be possible.

Test coverage with async/await can be challenging and there's nothing like real production usage to find bugs.  One pattern that you may consider is passing a correlation ID and logging it down the stack, then have a cascading timeout that logs the error.  This is more of a SOA pattern but at least it would give you a sense of where it's coming from.  We used this with Splunk to find deadlocks.